# event stream request not firing close event under passenger apache

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passenger, server-sent-events

So I have an event stream in my express js node application. Here's an overview:

```
app.get('/eventstream', function(req, res){

    req.socket.setTimeout(Infinity);

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    });

    res.write('/n');

    req.on('close', function(){
        console.log('connection closed');
    });

}
```

On my local dev box, running from the command line with

```
node app.js
```

it works fine, and prints out 'connection closed' when i close my tab in my browser.
However, when running on my server, under Apache with Passenger, it doesn't print out any message - the server seems to not fire the 'close' event. I'm using this event to remove from my count of active users. Any ideas?

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 3):

Phusion Passenger author here. The short answer is: technically, the connection hasn't closed yet.

Here's the long answer. If the client connects directly to your Node.js process, then yes, the connection is closed. But with Phusion Passenger there's a proxy in between the client and Node.js. The thing about sockets is that there are two ways to find out whether a socket has been closed: either 1) by reading end-of-file from it, or 2) by writing to it and getting an error. Phusion Passenger stops reading from the client as soon as it has determined that the request body has ended. And in case of GET requests, that is immediately after header. Thus, the only way Phusion Passenger can notice that the client has closed to the connection, is by sending data to it. But your application never sends any data after that newline, and so Phusion Passenger doesn't do that either and never notices that the connection is closed.

This issue is not limited to Phusion Passenger. If you put your Node.js app behind a load balancer or any other kind of reverse proxy, then you could also run into the same issue.

The standard solution is to regularly send "ping" messages, with the purpose of checking whether the connection is alive.

[A similar issue also applies to WebSockets.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phusion-passenger/yYzz7MnAvts/vtseJ7BCniAJ) It is the reason why the WebSocket supports ping frames.

**UPDATE February 28, 2016:**

We have found a solution, and Passenger 5.0.26 and later supports forwarding half-close events which fixes the problem described by @coffeedougnuts. Just use 5.0.26 and later and it'll work as expected.

Comment: Thanks very much for getting back to me! You answer cleared up a few things. I guess I can subscribe to the event stream client-side direct to the app port rather than via the port 80 proxy? That way, my event stream can close..?

Comment: Phusion Passenger does not expose your Node.js app on a publicly accessible port, so your client cannot access it directly. Your best bet is still to introduce ping messages.